# .NET MVC get route template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, httpcontext

Assume I have a controller with the route template `/users/{userId}/profilePhoto`

Say one user visits `/users/123/profilePhoto` and another visits `/users/444/profilePhoto`.

Is there any way I can find the route template (`/users/{userId}/profilePhoto`) that was used to resolve that request? Is it for example possible to read it out of the `HttpContext`?

Comment: Do You want to find ID in controllers action or somewhere else (like in FilterAttribute)?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want just a distinct value like `userId` or a complete string a la `/users/444/foo`?

Comment: The way I'm interpreting the question, the OP wants to get the route template for the current route.

Comment: @Marco, I updated the question after some googling led me to believe that what I'm looking for is the `Route Template`.

Comment: @garret I think I might end up needing both, but at least in the controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From within the controller action method:

```
((Route)RouteData.Route).Url
```

[`RouteData` is a property on the controller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.routedata(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.RouteData).  It has a [`Route` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routedata.route(v=vs.110).aspx) of type `RouteBase`, which *should* be castable to `Route`, which has a [`Url` property that contains the template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.route.url(v=vs.110).aspx).

From outside a controller action method, you do the same thing, but first you need to get the current request context:

```
((Route)HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Route).Url;
```

Comment: Interestingly you can see the Url property in the debugger of `Route` without casting it.

Comment: In the debugger, you're looking at the actual object.

Comment: @Amy's suggestion works. A variant of her approach can also be used if you're outside of the context of a controller: `((Route)HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Route).Url;`

Comment: @PetterBrodin I will add that to my answer, for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 1):

To get the currently used route in an action method you can simply do this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var route = this.RouteData.Route;
    return View();
}
```

`this` resolves to the current controller and can be ommitted. I just leave it in to remind myself of the current scope.